# ClearInterval is not working as expected with useRef in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created one setInterval which is being called on App Load, Like this

```
  let abc = true;
  let def = true;
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  if (abc) {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("hello console", def);
    }, 2000);
    abc = false;
  }
```

And trying to stop this interval using clearInterval on some click handler like this -

```
const clear = () => {
    clearTimeout(intervalRef.current);
    def = false;
    console.log(def);
  };
```

Issues I am facing right now are -

1. Why SetInterval is not stopped on click handler, while I am already cleared it in function?
2. Why value of `def` in not getting updated in setInterval.

**<kbd>[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-hooks-x9vgbv?file=/src/App.js:294-398)</kbd>**

PS: I am new in react, if this is silly mistake forgive me :)

Comment: You should declare variables and do some "logic" mainly using useState and useEffect hooks, with what you have now - variables are recreated on each render. setInterval is also called on each render, adding a new interval fn and rewriting previous intervalIds in the intervalRef.current, So only last intervalId is saved in intervalRef.current. Also, def is not getting updated due to it is closure-captured, you need to wrap it with useRef also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not a silly question, it's something I have seen many people struggling with. Let me clarify this:

1. Why `SetInterval` is not stopped on the click handler, while I am already cleared it in function?

> This is happening because your component is rendering more than once (so you are creating multiple intervals and only clearing the last one.

2. Why the value of def is not getting updated in `setInterval`.

> There are 2 things to consider here, first, the `setInterval` callback is not included in react lifecycle so the value does not get updated. Last, since you are only changing the value of a variable (but not the component state) the component will not be re-rendered and the code will remain the same.

You can find a very good article to deal with intervals in react here -> https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

I also leave you the code here as well as a code snippet link:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [runInterval, setRunInterval] = useState(true);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (runInterval) {
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setCounter((c) => c + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }; // clear interval when unmounting the component
  }, [runInterval]);

  const clear = () => {
    setRunInterval(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={() => clear()}>Click me to Stop Interval</h1>
      <h2>{counter}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-elbakyan-u5ezc3?file=/src/App.js:0-734

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation, can you please help me with the solution as well for these 2 points?

Answer (score 1):

1. Why SetInterval is not stopped on click handler, while I am already cleared it in function?

   One reason is that it should be `clearInterval` instead of `clearTimeout`.
2. Why value of def in not getting updated in setInterval.

   You should use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook to handle state in a component. Otherwise `abc` value gets newly created for each render o(when calling `App`) falling back to the initial value.

You need a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to handle it like below. If someone visits this component again and again and did not click clear then it will be a memory leak (since multiple intervals get cleated and never get distroyed). Need to handle it clearly when the component gets unmounted as well.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("hello JSG");
    }, 1000);
    // save the interval
    intervalRef.current = intervalId;
    // clear the interval
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    };
  }, []);

  const clear = () => {
    // clear the interval
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={() => clear()}>Click me to Stop Interval</h1>
      <h2>Please watch console!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working example:

[image: Edit pedantic-hypatia-uvuonk]

Comment: 1. tried with SetInterval as well, but not working. 
2. Why you return within useEffect? that doesn't mean it is clearingInterval immidiatly after creating one? 
3. on Call of Clear function will it clear last instance of setInterval or all?

Comment: 2. no it means that function gets called when your component get unmounted. ex: If you go back to another page. 3. It cleates only one when the component gets mounted and it get cleared if the user clicks or when unmounting always (guarantee no memory leaks)